# Why is my object inside of an array?

Tags: php, oop

I am doing the [codecourse php oop login/register tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc) and have run into some trouble. The issue I am having is with these lines:

```
    $user = new User();
    $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'));
```

These run conditionally on validation passing, which it does, because it returns no errors. I want to make this as simple as possible and don't think I need to include too much code because I think I have narrowed down the problem.

This is the code in my user class for the login function

```
    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
    $user = $this->find($username);
    print_r($this->_data);


    if($user) {
        if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
            echo 'OK!';
        } else {
            echo '<br>';
            echo 'This data password:';
            var_dump($this->data()->password);

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I know that my data is being retrieved, because I run print_r on ($this->data) and it returns the proper info for the user. So although my data is being retrieved, I think this is what is causing my error. This is the result of my print_r after failing to log in

```
    Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 32 
[email] => xxx 
[fname] => xxx 
[lname] => xxx 
[username] => user 
[password] => 295c7ac2341f2688838148728d450a5562933d5fbea6d2a9e9fec2eeab29dd84 
[salt] => 4ÌxÇd”0ð&ÞðÈßr¡–k$  «%•¦S?~d$r 
[name] => xxx 
[joined] => 2016-09-28 07:10:32 
[grouptype] => 1 ) )
```

The reason my $user->login method is not working is because the user is not an object, rather an array of the object (or at least that is what I have hypothesized) after finding a [semi working version of the code](https://github.com/christran/PHP-OOP-Login-Register-System) (login works, register does not) that returns the same data without the

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object
```

and is instead just simply

```
stdClass Object ( [id] =>
```

Why is my object inside of an array?

Comment: When you query your database, it returns a set of results as an array. Even if there's only one result. In your model, unpack the user data from the array, and return the object (i.e. `return $result[0]`).

Comment: Not sure about the framework you're using, but some have a `findOne()` as well as `find()` that returns either a single array or single object.  Or refer to `$this->data()[0]`